# Background proccesing system for serverless framework

Tags: background-process, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I need some solution for execution of background jobs. This should be done with serverless framework.
I want to find something similar to delay jobs that exist in RoR world.

Maybe anyone faced with such task and have some tools to recommend if any.

I will be grateful for any further information in scope of it, thanks.

Comment: What is "RoR world"?

Comment: RoR - Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 0):

Background jobs are typically implemented by tying together other AWS serverless services to manage retries or job state (as Lambda functions are stateless). As an example, it's typical to use API Gateway + Lambda to create API endpoints, and then implement background jobs by publishing jobs to SQS and consuming them with another Lambda function which can run longer than 30s (as it's not being invoked by API Gateway).

[Here's](https://blog.datumbrain.com/2021/12/06/background-process-in-lambda-using-sqs.html) an example of a pattern you might explore.